# auditctl comm vs. exe

Tags: command, executable, audit, linux-audit

I was looking at Linux audit reports. Here is a log from ausearch.

```
time->Mon Nov 23 12:30:30 2015  
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1448281830.422:222556): proctitle=6D616E006175736561726368  
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1448281830.422:222556): arch=c000003e syscall=56 success=yes exit=844 a0=1200011 a1=0 a2=0 a3=7f34afa999d0 items=0 ppid=830 pid=838 auid=1001 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=1 comm="nroff" exe="/usr/bin/bash" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
```

From my understanding the `comm` argument is the name the user used to invoke the `exe` binary. How come is `nroff` referring to `/usr/bin/bash`? Note that this is a general question, I have seen this kind of thing, which I cannot explain, happen many times. In this particular case, here is more data about nroff and bash on my system.

```
[root@localhost ~]# which nroff  
/bin/nroff  
[root@localhost ~]# ll -i /bin/nroff  
656858 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 3312 Jun 17 10:59 /bin/nroff  
[root@localhost ~]# ll -i /usr/bin/bash  
656465 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1071992 Aug 18 13:37 /usr/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nroff` "executable" provided by `groff` is a shell script, e.g.,

```
#! /bin/sh
# Emulate nroff with groff.
#
# Copyright (C) 1992, 1993, 1994, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003,
#               2004, 2005, 2007, 2009
#   Free Software Foundation, Inc.
#
# Written by James Clark, maintained by Werner Lemberg.

# This file is of `groff'.
```

Depending on the system you are using, `/bin/sh` may be a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/bash`, e.g., Fedora, which links `/bin` to `/usr/bin`.